# Display an background image trough table cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, center

I want to set a background image on the floating bar on the bottom of my page: https://hartbodenreiniger.info/.

But sadly the background image gets cutted by each table cell..

I already tried two things:

1.Convert the table to divs and set the background image. This is working but I cannot display the button in the middle and center of the floating bar. This is needed to convert a table to divs:

```
jQuery('#wpfront-notification-bar > table').replaceWith( jQuery('#wpfront-notification-bar > table').html()
   .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div id='table'")
   .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div")
   .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
   .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
   .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
   .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
);
```

How can I center the Button?

Or my second solution was to create a overlay div and set this div to `display:absolute;` with an background image. But same problem. How do I center the button and also there is the problem that the overlay wrapper is above the text..

I think way 1 is the better way but how can I center that?
Do you have any idea or any other solution?

Kind regards

Comment: Center the button vertically?

Comment: Yes, horizontal is easy. It's just `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `line-height` property. Try the code below and see the differences

```css
.container{
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.the-button{
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100px;
}

button{
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="the-button">
    <button>Hello</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div style="height:100%;">
    <button>Hi</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this responsive?